# Shared element transition, blink when scale down image

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-transitions

https://youtu.be/n8MdHNYozgs
I implemented shared element transition between fragment and activity like on the video above

```
 val intent = Intent(context, Main2Activity::class.java)

    val list = ArrayList<Pair<View, String>>()
    (recyclerView.adapter as Adapter).list.forEachIndexed { index, entity ->
        val itemView = recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(index)?.itemView
        if (itemView != null) {
            list.add(Pair(itemView, entity.id.toString()))
        }
    }
    val options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(activity, *list.toTypedArray())
    startActivity(intent, options.toBundle())
```

And in the activity I display views in another recycler view. 
Could you please give me an advice what I should do to avoid blinking at the end of scaling down images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The thing is I used itemView as view for transition:

```
val itemView = recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(index)?.itemView
    if (itemView != null) {
        list.add(Pair(itemView, entity.id.toString()))
    }
```

But need to use the following code:

```
 val holder = MyRecyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(index)
        if (holder != null) {
            with(holder as MyViewHolder) {
                list.add(Pair(this.image, entity.id.toString()))
            }
        }
```

And everything works fine.